# Setting DATE as default column type for esriFieldTypeDate in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, oracle-dbms, arccatalog, date, geodatabase-xml

If I use esriFieldTypeDate with ArcGIS 10.2 a DATE column is created in Oracle.

If I use it in ArcGIS 10.6 a TIMESTAMP(6) is used

Is there a way to set DATE as default column type for esriFieldTypeDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 10.4 the supported Oracle data type for esriFieldTypeDate switched to TIMESTAMP.  I don't think there is any way around this if the data is created within the ArcGIS Environment.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/data-types-oracle.htm

Comment: Maybe there is an error in ArcObject because if I store the following value (C#):
   DateTime.Parse("9999-01-01T00:00:00Z")

the table will contain
   01.01.9999 00:59:59.000000